# How to get request.session in Vue.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I'm trying to do authentication in my web site, so I've used express-session and tested with Postman.

Everything go well, but testing with Vue.js it's cannot get session, so how do I get the session on Vue.js.

app.js (Node.js)

```
router.post('/login', urlencodedParser, ldapAuth, async (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.session)
        if (!req.session.username) {
            res.status(401).send('Auth failed, please log in.');
        }
    });

router.get('/session', async (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.session)
        if (req.session.username && req.cookies.user_sid) {
            res.status(200).send(req.session)
        } else {
            res.status(401).send('Auth failed, please log in.');
        }
    })
```

login.vue

```
methods: {
    login: e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      let username = e.target.elements.username.value;
      let password = e.target.elements.password.value;
      let login = () => {
        let data = {
          username: username,
          password: password
        };
        PostServices.login(data)
          .then(res => {
            router.push("/content");
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      };
      login();
    }
  }
```

content.vue

```
methods: {
    async getContent() {
      const response = await GetServices.fetchSession();
      console.log(response);
      this.cont = response.session;
    }
  }
```

here some console.log output

http request with postman => https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFCcf.jpg

http request with vue.js => https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0pYF.jpg